# DOM multilanguage for offline web app

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, dom, multilingual

I choose for my off-line application development HTML5, Javascript, AJAX, etc.

For multi-language support, I introduce a (not-yet) custom element  with the following documentation.

The implementation works file, but can you please tell me if something goes wrong about my architecture?

```
<x-lang
text="substitute this text" // Optional. Inner text or inner hierarchy of element
                            // <x-lang> change to lang.lang['en']['substitute this text']
lang="en" // AFTER substitution, indicates the language of substitution.
attr="alt" // Optional. Instead of <x-lang> inner, substitution will be
           // done on next non-<x-lang> sibling <element alt="...">
src="file" // Optional. Must be on first <x-lang> element of document. AJAX loading file
           // 'lang/en.file.json' with "key"="value" lines. If exist, "type" attr must exist.
type="json" // Can be "xml" or "blob" if key substituted with a hierarchy instead of
            // plain text. Exist only if attr "src" exist.
sibling="true" // Optional special case. Instead of substitute inner text of <x-lang>,
               // create (1st time) or edit (next time) a next sibling text node.
               // Substitution can only be plain text. Not a hierarchy.
substitution="delayed" // Optional. If type="blob" and element is not visible, don't load
                       // tons. Wait for a signal.
```

A substituted sample:

```
<div>A brown <x-lang text="fox" lang="en">fox</x-lang> jumps:</div>
<x-lang text="A fox!" attr="alt" lang="en" /><img src="fox.jpg" alt="a fox!" />
<svg><text><x-lang text="Width" sibling="true" lang="en"/>Width: 10cm</text></svg>
```

As you can see, in svg text, `<x-lang>` cannot have the text inner. Must be sibling.

Of course, javascript translation works like this: (core translation files already loaded)

```
alert(lang.translate('AJAX request timed out'));
```